# Updating ionic with command?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I just installed `ionic` CLI@5.4.4. It is latest version.
But When I started new project it installed `"@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1"`, `"@angular/core": "~8.1.2"` and so on. So not latest versions :/

How should I update those?
`ng update @ionic/angular @angular/core @angular/cli` ?
Or maybe simply update `package.json` file?

Comment: Ionic cli is as command line interface (CLI). 
You already have the latest version of ionic.

Comment: `ionic/cli` is latest but `@ionic/angular` and `@angular/core` are not though started with latest `ionic/cli`

Comment: You can try something like that to update your version : npm install ionic-angular@latest --save

Answer (score 0):

You can also just modify your package.json and run npm install.